# How to blend the color from different views in iPhone

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, blend

I draw two diagrams with different colors in different views(`UIView`) and applied pan gesture recognizer on both of them. When i drag one diagram to another diagram, they are coincided or intersected to each other. I want to combine the color on that intersection part.

Suppose one view has red colored diagram and another one has green colored diagram then the intersection part will be yellow color as shown in the following picture. This is my part what i want without using openGLES.

I know how to blend the color from different diagrams in same view(`UIView`) by using `kCGBlendModeDifference` but my case is in different views. I have tried but i couldn't get it.Please can any one help to me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any good way of doing this other than drawing the resulting image yourself (using, say, core graphics or OpenGL). You can keep the existing views for dragging & positioning; just make them transparent and draw the circles underneath yourself.